# List points with integer coordinates on a scaled standard simplex

Tags: algorithms

Given two positive integers:

- $d \in \mathbb{N}^+$ space dimension
- $s \in \mathbb{N}^+$ expected sum

list all the points $(x_1, .. x_d) \in \mathbb{N}^d$ such that
$$\sum_{i=1}^d x_i = s$$

Expected output:

- For $d = 2$ and $s = 3$ the algorithm should output (3, 0), (2, 1), (1, 2), (0, 3).
- For $d = 3$ and $s = 1$ the algorithm should output (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1).

What is the most efficient algorithm to achieve this?

Comment: Let's upvote instead of downvote? I thought it looked like an interesting problem to discuss. Furthermore it is not covered much on the web, so it may be useful to other people.

Comment: Welcome to [cs.se]. Unfortunately, the Q&A format of this site isn't well suited for open ended discussion. Your question will likely be received better if you ask a _specific question_ about this problem. See also [these tips](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a better question.

Comment: @Discretelizard Thank you, I've refined the question. Do you think [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com) is the right place to ask for a specific code-agnostic algorithm like this one?

Comment: What's wrong with a recursive solution?  Any recursive solution can be trivially modified to be non-recursive by making the call stack explicit, so I don't see the point of such a requirement.  Also as there are exponentially many such points, any algorithm needs to take exponential time, so in general there is no solution that is efficient.

Comment: @D.W. you are right. However I'm not sure whenever calculating $f(b,k) \forall b < d, \forall k < s$ is really necessary here.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: let's say $f(d, s) = \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}^{d}$ is the solution to your problem. Then you have recursive solution:

$$f(d, s) = \bigcup_{k=0}^s \left [ (k) \times f(d-1, s-k)\right]$$
$$f(1, s) = (s)$$

Where $(k)$ is the unary tuple containing $k$ and $\times$ is the Cartesian product.

Comment: Indeed, I was thinking of such the recursive solution too. However, it is rather costly: $f(d, s)$ requires to pre-calculate $f(b, k) \forall b < d, \forall k < s$.

Are you aware of a more efficient solution?

Comment: This solution runs in near linear time (and perhaps can be implemented to run in linear time).